# Is PlayStore dimming the screenshots?

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot, google-play-console

I upload 1440*2560 resolution , `.png` type screenshots to the Play Console. When I view in the gallery on my device they look good, but in the Google Play App they look much worse. How can I achieve the same quality in the Play Store screenshots section? Does anyone else have the same issue?

[image: This is the case]

Comment: PNG is a lossless format and you shouldn't experience any deterioration in quality,  mean the problem could be in your playstore picture viewer, can you check using your browser just to be sure

Comment: thx, as you pointed it looks normal on desktop's playstore webpage. But the problem(lower quality) is on mobile Play Store application which we don't have alternatives from using it for sure.

Comment: I've seen this before, it's very uncommon so don't u worry about how others will see your app's screenshots ;)

Comment: if you find my comment helpful , upvote it if u like ;)

Answer (score 2):

The Play store resizes screenshots to match the size and device resolution of the device it is sending it to. For most screenshots this works absolutely fine, and is only what the device would do itself.

The problem with your screenshots is probably the fireworks. In a very similar way that [confetti ruins video compression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6Rp-uo6HmI) your very detailed fireworks graphics are one of the classic examples of graphics that don't resize well.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it too much. But if you are concerned, Google Play offers a way to do [Store listing Experiments](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/grow/store-listing-experiments) to find what screenshots encourage the most users to install your App. You could try different options there, including ones with more block color that resize better.

Comment: Thank you Nick, especially fireworks picture was manipiluated badly as you said, but  the other pictures also were dimmed significantly and looks with less contrast& less attraction. There is nothing to do at this point I guess& thanks for trying to help

Comment: I'm also having this issue with screenshots being reduced in quality via the Play store app (and it's not confetti related). Did you figure anything out?